# Is it possible to trigger the system dialog for requestAuthorization for Push Notifications multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to ask the user to allow push notifications again after a while, when they initially said "no".

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorization) reads as this would not be possible:

> The user may grant or deny authorization, and the system stores the user’s response so that subsequent calls to this method do not prompt the user again.

My demo confirms that.

Despite that, did anyone find a way to do this?

Comment: Then you have to check the access and show a custom dialog as most of the apps do. Showing the steps and opening the settings app.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to ask the user again about push-notification. You can check the push-notification is enable or disable for your application using code and then the user must have to enable the push-notifications from the settings and again that will not ask for push-notifications using alert/popup.

The best practice is to check if user has allowed app to send a push-notification. if user has not allowed the app to send push-notification you can ask user to allow the push-notification permission from the app's setting by presenting a custom/native alert to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: NO (Currently there is no way to ask the user again about Push Notification permission, until or unless user reinstalls the app.)

---

But you can check the permissions and open settings app.
Code for checking and opening settings app:

```
func askForLocationPermission() {
        let status  = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "your title", message: "your message", preferredStyle: .alert)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                switch action.style{
                case .default: if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)! as URL, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    }
                case .cancel: print("cancel")
                case .destructive: print("destructive")
                @unknown default: break
                }
            }))
        }
    }
```